# Why would a person or bot visit my "about us" page three times every day?

Tags: ip-address, multilingual, hacking, botattack

Something strange happens on my site (which is on 6 languages):
I use statcounter for monitoring the website.
In the last 3-4 months, I observed that at least 3 times per day, one page is "visited", always from different IP, 99.9% from US, always the same page but in different language, randomly. The page is "about us", and always it happens within several minutes (the 3 visits). Always from Chrome 65, Win10, 3 pages of about us each visit.

Why should a bot or person do it? I checked the site with several "hacking testers" and it looks clean. Does it look a hacking activity?

Comment: It doesn't sound very malicious to me, but I can't really guess why they would do it.

Comment: Thank you very much Stephen. Should I block the "about me" files in robots.txt?

Comment: There is no reason here to suggest you should block this in `robots.txt`.

Comment: Why do you think it would be suspicious?

Comment: Of course I am. Usually, people don't spend time or money without a certain reason. If would be 1000 times, I could understand the point. But it happens 3-4 times per day, each time from a different IP, and always the same pages ("about us") in different languages. Doesn't look suspicious to you? Does it look a normal action?

Comment: I've been having a similar problem. The IPs are residential, mainyl from Asia, requesting about 35,000 pages per day for 30,000 IPs, using slightly altered user agents - Chrome 49. Try searching for the user agent to see if it is fake. The user agent they use to hit my site has the wrong version of Webkit for Chrome 49 - it doesn't exist, except for scrappers, so I was able to block the user agent and am currently free from this traffic. I have no idea why anyone would do this.